# Handling file with Python

Tags: python

I´m trying to extract a specific information from a file using Python:

My file looks like:

```
XXXXX         AIR-CAP1532E-Z-K9     YYYYY  ZZZZZ  WWWWW
XXXXX         AIR-CAP1532E-Z-K9     YYYYY  ZZZZZ  WWWWW
XXXXX         AIR-CAP1532E-Z-K9     YYYYY  ZZZZZ  WWWWW
XXXXX         AIR-CAP1532E-Z-K9     YYYYY  ZZZZZ  WWWWW
```

The script I wrote, as follow:

```
for line in fin:
     if 'AIR'  in line:
         list = line.split(" ")
         fout.write(list[0] + '\n')
```

It gives me the whole first column as `list[0]`. But I need thoses elements item by item. I need to take each 'XXXXX'  element and store it in a variable but have no clue how to do that.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Odd. I tried the code and works in mine. `list[0]` returns XXXXX.

Comment: Can you post an actual excerpt of the file? As @romain-aga points out, it is difficult to know exactly what needs to be done without knowing how the lines are spaced (i.e. tabs, or spaces).

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are writing the 'xxxxx' elements to a file `fout`. If you want to store those elements in python you could use a dictionary:

```
dict = {}
i = 0
for line in fin:
    if 'AIR'  in line:
        list = line.split(" ")
        fout.write(list[0] + '\n')
        dict['line' + 'i'] = list[0]
        i += 1
```

Then you could access them by calling `dict[lineX]` where x is the zero indexed line you want.